# Checked checkboxes with comma separated values from mysql database using laravel and vue js

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to check checkboxes with values coming from the database in Laravel vue js. I have already added the selected items in a value separated format to the database. Now I want to edit the added values by binding them to the appropriate checkboxes.

here is part of the code

```js
            SelectRestaurant:function(id)
                   {

                        var _this = this;
                        this.RestaurantObject.id =  id;
                        var input = this.RestaurantObject;
                        axios.post('getRestaurant', input).then(function(response){
                        _this.RestaurantObject = response.data;


                    }).catch(function(error){
                        alert('Could not load record. Please try again');

                    })

                 },
```

```html
<label>Select Restaurant Types</label>
        <!--<select name="type_id" id="type_id" class="form-control text-small" v-model='form.type_id' multiple>
                                            <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select Restaurant Types</option>
                        <option v-for='t in types' :value='t.id'>@{{ t.type_name }}</option>
                                            </select>-->




                                          <ul>
        <li v-for="t in types" style="display: inline-block; list-style:none; padding:7px">
          <input type="checkbox" :value="t.id" v-model="RestaurantObject.type_id">

          <label :for="t.id">@{{ t.type_name }}</label>
        </li>



   </ul>


Vue js codes

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing your Vuejs data object? Meanwhile, you could do

```js
<li v-for="t in types" style="display: inline-block; list-style:none; padding:7px">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="t.id" v-model="RestaurantObject.type_id" :checked="types.includes('RestaurantObject.type_id')">
  <label :for="t.id">@{{ t.type_name }}</label>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen wonder. I tried the answer you provided but I am getting this error: includes is not a function.

Comment: I updated the comment. Can you try again? @Emmanuel